# Post XMl data to a webservice via YQL

Tags: web-services, post, yql

I have a vendor, that i need to post XML data to their Webservice that will give me a response which will get displayed via Javascript in the tabular format.

I was using xmlhttp object or Ajax, but that will result me in getting Cross site scripting alert box in IE.
So i thought i will use YQL , but nowhere i could find a way to post data to the webservices via YQL. are there any examples. is this possible?

I even tried "Select * from http://stagingimport.brassring.com/WebRouter/WebRouter.asmx/route where Query = ...". this webservice does not accept JSON data.

Or are there any similar things like YQL that will do that.
I am using SharePoint and would not want to go through server side solution , as this is a temporary solution of what we are trying to achieve.

I am going to this URL http://stagingimport.brassring.com/WebRouter/WebRouter.asmx/route that is a webservice and requires xml data send them via post.

I would appreciate your input.

Thanks

Rahul

Comment: Hi , 
Is there anyone who can think,it's even possible.
or am i asking the wrong question.
Ideally i think it cannot as it's (YQL) a read / Scrape only service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys,
i think i found it.
The answer is Yes, you can do it. i opened up a Yahoo console and wrote something like

```
 select * from xml where url='http://import.brassring.com/WebRouter/WebRouter.asmx/route?inputXml=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859- .........
```

and it did return me the record, although it was not JSON as they only return XML inside an XML.

Today I also tried ql.io from Ebay and I was also able to get the expected return value.

Hope it will help someone, Can't give the whole code as stated above as it is authenticated.